# How to declare generic method with parameter Array<Codable>?

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to write a short and extensible method for requesting data from the server.

This code is not compiled:

```
func getData<DataType>(url: String, completion : @escaping ((DataType) -> ())) where DataType: Array<Codable>? {
    //
}
```

Error: `Type 'DataType' constrained to non-protocol, non-class type 'Array<Codable>?' (aka 'Array<Decodable & Encodable>')`

Bad workaround that I could find:

```
func getData<RecordType>(url: String, completion : @escaping ((Array<RecordType>?, RecordType) -> ())) where RecordType: Codable {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend  not to constrain to Array. A generic type can be **both** a single object or an array. However constrain the protocol only to `Decodable`

```
func getData<DataType>(url: String, completion : @escaping (DataType) -> Void) where DataType: Decodable {
    //
}
```

And you could also return a possible error with the generic `Result` type

```
func getData<DataType>(url: String, completion : @escaping (Result<DataType,Error>) -> Void) where DataType: Decodable {
    //
}
```

`()` and `Void` are synonyms, but in completion handlers which require a lot of parentheses anyway it's easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
func getData<RecordType: Codable>(url: String, completion : @escaping (([RecordType]?, RecordType) -> ())) { // }
```

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to StackOverflow. On this site answers should have a description to explain the problem they solve (for example, if someone doesn't have the original question in front of them). Please edit the answer with a brief explanation. In the future someone may delete your answer if is code-only.